# Javascript function does not exist during runtime

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a Javascript function in a separate `jsp file:` (used `<jsp:include>` for file inclusion)

```
function tickMembership(code){}
```

when invoked using `onclick` in an html element, the following error occurs:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tickMembership is not defined

Any idea on how this might happen? The script is there even when inspecting the sources in the browser. I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML? Can you confirm the Javascript is loaded using Chrome's Developer Tools -> Network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the eventListener on load of the dom.

or if you are inserting the html dynamically you can use jquery 'on' method.

Comment: Apparently, from the information he posted, there was nothing wrong with the event listener. The onclick event obviously fires, so the problem should lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It is a caching issue the browser is caching the .JS file clear the browser cache and try

Happy Coding.